# How to install the Open Source Intel drivers to get OpenGL 4.5?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, opengl, mesa, open-source

I cannot find the open source Intel GPU drivers for OpenGL 4.5 as stated here:
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Intel-Driver-GL45-Certified

I have just upgraded, installed, my Ubuntu 16.04 (Lenovo L460 with i5-6200U) with x-swat PPA 
https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/ubuntu/updates

Now my system has Mesa 17.3.3 which is quite recent. (mesa is right now on version 18)

But (unless I am reading this wrong) my system is still using OpenGL 3.0

```
$ glxinfo | grep 'version'
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.3.3
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.3.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 17.3.3
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

I am on kernel 4.13 in Ubuntu 16.04

```
$ uname -a
Linux 4.13.0-32-generic #35~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 10:13:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is glmark2:

```
 glmark2
=======================================================
    glmark2 2014.03+git20150611.fa71af2d
=======================================================
    OpenGL Information
    GL_VENDOR:     Intel Open Source Technology Center
    GL_RENDERER:   Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) 
    GL_VERSION:    3.0 Mesa 17.3.3
```

So I take that my system is still using OpenGL 3.0.

I assumed that being these new OpenGL 3.5 drivers for Intel, open source, they would come bundled with mesa, right?

Any help in what I am assuming wrong, reading wrong or missing?

Thanks

Comment: Since there are no direct references to source or binaries, you should direct those questions to Intel. Also ask if the OpenGL 4.5 certification is relevant to Skylake, which is now a few years old. Do point out that you want non-vague answers.

Comment: Your system is capable of OpenGL 4.5 as shown by the "core profile version string".

Comment: @gsxruk thanks. I was in doubt as glmark2 was showing only GL_VERSION 3.0. but i guess that this is just what glmark2 uses.

Comment: I believe that it is just reporting your "OpenGL version string". As I understand it, glmark2 is an OpenGL 2 benchmark so I doubt it is using anything as high as 3.0.

Comment: @AlexN did you manage to upgrade to `OpenGL 4.5`? I'm facing the same issue right now ...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Updated Open Graphics Drivers PPA:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers

$ sudo apt-get update
```

Comes from this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers?field.series_filter=bionic